# Using socket.io with redux

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, redux, react-redux

This is the first time I am going to use `socket.io` in production. I am using `React` + `Redux`. I have recently integrated `socket.io` with redux and its working fine but I am not sure if it would be the best way to do how I have done. Because I haven't found any sort of proper implementations of socket.io with redux, I need some help/suggestions on ways if I can improve it.

So, for starters I have setup a service for managing sockets all over the app:

**Socket.js**

```
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import storage from '../storage';

/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */

const Socket = {
  connect,
  emit,
  on,
  removeListener,
  socket: null
};

/* eslint-enable no-use-before-define */

function connect() {
  const hasAuthenticated = !isEmpty(storage.get('user'));
  if (hasAuthenticated) {
    // Setup a server for testing.
    Socket.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', { reconnect: true });
  }
}

connect();

function on(eventName, callback) {
  if (Socket.socket) {
    Socket.socket.on(eventName, data => {
      callback(data);
    });
  }
}

function emit(eventName, data) {
  if (Socket.socket) {
    Socket.socket.emit(eventName, data);
  }
}

function removeListener(eventName) {
  if (Socket.socket) {
    Socket.socket.removeListener(eventName);
  }
}

export default Socket;
```

I have only used it with a single page, but ofcourse there will be more pages. My redux compositon for that page is:

**Dashboard.jsx**

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.alertViolations(); // Action
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.unsubscribeViolations(); // Action
  }
```

**Actions.js**

```
export function alertViolations() {
  return dispatch => {
    Socket.on('violations', violation => {
      dispatch(actions.updateViolations(violation));
    });
  };
}

export function unsubscribeViolations() {
  Socket.removeListener('violations');
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(actions.removeViolationsListener());
  };
}
```

Its working fine. On unmounting it stops listening to the emit function that I have on server. I would really appreciate if I could get some suggestions regarding:

- Do I need to setup a middleware to managing sockets in a more better
  and abstract way?
- Is there a better way to manage sockets with redux?
- How can I make use of the built in `connect` and
  `disconnect` functions?
- The way I have handled to only build the connection if user has authentication, is that fine? Or could there be a better way to handle this as well?
- Oh and also, if I want to remove the connection on logout? Would I just have to removeListeners from all methods or can I use the disconnect function on logout actions?

Thanks a lot. Please let me know if I have missed anything in explaining.

Answer (score 6):

Middleware is the most common place for a persistent connection like a websocket in a Redux app.  There's a good number of existing Redux+websocket integration libraries already - see my list at https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/middleware.md#sockets-and-adapters .  You may be able to use some of them as-is, or use them as examples for your own implementation.